# AppFabric asynchronous WCF services duration time

Tags: appfabric

In Windows Server AppFabric IIS dashboard, I see call duration 0 for some of the WCF services, while it is clearly not 0 (IIS logs also prove that). This only happens to asynchronous services (task-based async). Is this expected? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is it perhaps that by design asynchronous operations return immediately?

Comment: Well, they don't. They just don't block worker thread, while waiting for responses from calls to other services or database calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppFabric WCF statistics share many things with WCF performance counters & WCF analytic tracing.

Unfortunately, when working with async operation call duration, call duration is simply not supported because of the worker/IO thread switch.

You can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734725.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824970/async-wcf-service-and-call-duration-performance-counter) more informations

> When used on an asynchronous WCF service the Call Duration counter
>   will always return -1.

You can try to emit [user-defined events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/11/02/getting-the-most-out-of-user-events-and-windows-server-appfabric-monitoring.aspx) to track operations duration, but this will be be visible in the dashboard.